# how to check if button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i make a button i want to add check if button is clicked then some code work here is my code:
i make a button i want to add check if button is clicked then some code work here is my code:

```
$("body").on('change', '.quantity', function() {
        var that = $(this);
        if ($('#btnAdd').is(':clicked')){
            $('#itemscounter').val("1");
            var counter=$('#itemscounter').val();
            var quantity=$('#quantity').val();
            var unitprice=$('#unitprice').val();
            var linetotal=quantity*unitprice;
            that.parent().find('.linetotal').val(linetotal) 
            $("#invoicetotalamount").val(+linetotal)
            var discount=document.getElementById('discount').value ;
            var discountamount= discount/100 * linetotal;
            var amount=linetotal-discountamount;
            $("#balanceamount").val(+amount);
        }
        else{           
        var counter=$('#itemscounter').val();
        var quantity=$('#quantity').val();
        var unitprice=$('#unitprice').val();
        var linetotal=quantity*unitprice;
        $('#linetotal').val(+linetotal);
         var sum=linetotal;
        for (i = 2; i <=counter; i++) {
            var quantity=$('#quantity' + i).val();
            var unitprice=$('#unitprice' + i).val();
            var linetotal=quantity*unitprice;
            $('#linetotal' + i).val(+linetotal);            
            sum=+sum +(+(linetotal));           
            }
        $("#invoicetotalamount").val(+sum); 
        var discount=document.getElementById('discount').value ;
        var discountamount= discount/100 * sum;
        var amount=sum-discountamount;
        $("#balanceamount").val(+amount);
        }

    });
```

but when i click it not work,how i do this?

Comment: `$('#btnAdd').click(function(){...})` ?

Comment: What do you think what is the purpose of click event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(function(){
  $("#btnAdd").click(, function() {
   alert("Button Clicked");
       // Your Code
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is [`click`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event:

```
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {
   // ...
});
```

Comment: or a shortcut version: $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
   // ...
});

Comment: i don,t use click function i just checked if button is clicked then code run

Comment: @user2833510 Button element is stateless opposite to checkbox or radio button. If you use checkbox or radio `:checked` state is applicable.

Answer (score 0):

You have click event for that   [**SEE HERE**](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

```
$("selector").on("click", function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you want something like this:

```
$("#btnAdd").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
    if($(this).hasClass('clicked')){
       // do something
    }else{
       // do something else
    }
});
```